# associative array execution order problem

Tags: bash, shell-script, for, associative-array

in a bash script i'm using an associative array to create tables, tablespaces, indexes and partitions in my database. this is the script (the main script is too long with complicated queries so i summarize it into something smaller):

```
#!/bin/bash
##**** definition of variables ****
DB2PATH=/bin/db2
DBNAME=mydb
SchemaName=customer
declare -A tables
tables=( [REQUEST]=REQ [RESPONS]=RES [METHOD]=MTH )

for t in "${!tables[@]}"
do
key=${tables[$t]}

$DB2PATH -x "SELECT HIGHVALUE as LastHighValue FROM SYSCAT.DATAPARTITIONS 
WHERE TABSCHEMA='$SchemaName' AND TABNAME='$t' AND 
DATAPARTITIONNAME=$key "  
done
```

i changed all of `$DB2PATH -x` with `echo` to check the generated commands before execution and i got this output:

```
SELECT HIGHVALUE as LastHighValue FROM SYSCAT.DATAPARTITIONS
WHERE TABSCHEMA='customer' AND TABNAME='METHOD' AND DATAPARTITIONNAME=MTH
SELECT HIGHVALUE as LastHighValue FROM SYSCAT.DATAPARTITIONS
WHERE TABSCHEMA='customer' AND TABNAME='RESPONS' AND DATAPARTITIONNAME=RES
SELECT HIGHVALUE as LastHighValue FROM SYSCAT.DATAPARTITIONS
WHERE TABSCHEMA='customer' AND TABNAME='REQUEST' AND DATAPARTITIONNAME=REQ
```

i defined my associative array with this order `REQUEST,RESPONS,MTH` but the out put is in reverse order and in my main script the order is `REQUEST,RESPONS,MTH` but i get this order `REQUEST,MTH,RESPONS`.
in main script there are so much relational commands that connect tables together so it's really important that the commands be executed as the order that is defined in array.
why this happens and how i can fix this?

Comment: See also https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2019-08/msg00032.html

Comment: associative arrays in bash are unordered, so this is normal.  if you need to preserve the order, then use a separate **indexed** array.  e.g. `order=(REQUEST RESPONS METHOD)`, and loop over that (e.g. `for t in "${order[@]"}`)